# Java Kafka consumer cannot read any topic records

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

I've tried out [this great tutorial](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) for starting multiple Kafka brokers in my local environment through Docker. I'm able to start a producer in one terminal window and receive messages when I start the consumer in another terminal window. To do this, I ran:

```
./start-kafka-shell.sh <my public ip> 10.224.49.140:2181
```

as the tutorial says, and then proceeded to start the producer:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic=topic --broker-list=`broker-list.sh`
```

and the consumer:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic=topic --zookeeper=$ZK
```

Now I'm writing a Java consumer on my local environment and trying to connect to the Kafka port exposed through Docker. Here are the Java configs:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "<my public IP>:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
    props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    SimpleConsumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(props, 
    Arrays.asList("topics"));
```

And... nothing happens when I produce messages through the producer. Here is the only log I can see output from the Java consumer side:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - 
ConsumerConfig values: 
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
group.id = test-consumer-group
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
bootstrap.servers = [10.224.49.140:9092]
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
enable.auto.commit = true
ssl.key.password = null
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
ssl.truststore.password = null
session.timeout.ms = 30000
metrics.num.samples = 2
client.id = 
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
key.deserializer = class 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
ssl.protocol = TLS
check.crcs = true
request.timeout.ms = 40000
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.keystore.location = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
fetch.min.bytes = 1
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
auto.offset.reset = latest

Listening to topics...
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version 
: 0.9.0.1
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId 
: 23c69d62a0cabf06
```

I believe this is a "coordinator not found" issue, because I skimmed through the code while stepping through it -- but I can't find the the code that I suspect is causing the issue anymore. I also can't seem to enable logs at INFO level across my application, still wrestling with that.

I'm using a Kafka 0.9.0 client (org.apache.kafka-kafka-clients, version 0.9.0.1), and I am reasonably sure the tutorial is also using Kafka 0.9.0.

Anyone have this issue before or can point me to what I'm missing with coordinators and/or configs? Why would my application have an issue with finding a coordinator if it's the only consumer running?

I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

**Edit #1:** 
Following cricket_007's response, I followed the Confluent Docker quickstart, and I'm still running into trouble:

`Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {mytopic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

I've tried changing the `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port`. Still no luck. I'll try Docker Machine.

**Edit #2:**

I've installed Docker Machine, but before running it, noticed these logs:

`[2018-06-23 15:12:26,497] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2018-06-23 15:12:26,501] INFO Result of znode creation at /brokers/ids/0 is: OK (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2018-06-23 15:12:26,503] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(127.0.0.1,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT)) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
....
[2018-06-23 15:13:01,657] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)`

Now I'm confused. It sounds like a broker with id=0 has in fact been started up and has registered itself. So why would this error above be thrown?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version for Kafka? My suggestion would be to look at the Confluent Docker quickstart... There's no reason to start with multiple brokers because one computer can only process so much data at once, regardless of having containers

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why the tutorial used such an old version. Thanks for the suggestion. I've switched to using the Confluent Docker quickstart, and I'm still running into trouble: 
`Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {mytopic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}` I've tried changing the advertised.host.name and advertised.port. Still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably a docker network problem. Can you [edit] your question to include the new steps you've done? Also, I believe if running on Mac or Windows, using Docker Machine is recommended